# pyvista implementation vtk swept surface class

Tags: 3d, visualization

I want to create a poly line (I think in pv this is an array of line cells) and display it with an ellipse round the line (not a tube). VTK that pyvista is built off has a class to do this but it isn't ported into pyVista. There is function to produce a ribbon but I can't see any way to thicken this into an ellipse (or near enough)

This is for a program that currently calls blender to display a line with what blender calls a bevel running along it.

it's horrible over kill to use blender just to do a single visualisation task.

Has anyone got a good idea how to do this. (could be a lot of points involved

I have had a good search of PyVista interface and looked at VTK that underlies it then got frightened on how to import the underlying vtk class into python myself.